# Using IFS with echo

Tags: bash, ifs

Why does this:

```
arr=(1 2 4 8 16)
IFS=,
echo "${arr[*]}"
```

print out `1,2,4,8,16` (which is what I want) but this doesn't:

```
arr=(1 2 4 8 16)
IFS=, echo "${arr[*]}"
```

?

I'd like to have a temporary `IFS` without having to set it then reset/unset it.

Comment: `IFS=, command eval 'echo "${arr[*]}"'` or `(IFS=,; echo "${arr[*]}")`. More info on the first one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92187/setting-ifs-for-a-single-statement), the second one is just creating a subshell to define the IFS for its duration

Comment: `arr=(1 2 4 8 16); (IFS=,; echo "${arr[*]}")`

Comment: Order of events: the array expansion happens *before* `echo` (with its modified version of `IFS`) runs. You need to modify `IFS` for the *shell* (as in the first example), not for `echo` (which ignores its inherited value of `IFS`).

Comment: Thanks all.  "Order of events" is what made it click for me.  And thanks for the duplicates, @Cyrus: you're obviously better at searching than I am!