# Why does this IFS variable assignment not affect the cmd it precedes?

Tags: bash, ifs

Consider this bash session:

```
set -- 1 2 3
echo "$*"          # 1 2 3  (as expected)
IFS=a echo "$*"    # 1 2 3  (why not "1a2a3"?)
IFS=a; echo "$*"   # 1a2a3a (as expected)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1REFXV8FQwUjBmCs1OSNfQUlFS0kBDpQhUgoKGonFCqkVBanJJakpmlyebsG2iQoo6hEqyzMqFfLySxSUDBONEo2V7KHKrVHUA5WDZBNRDf7/HwA)

Why does the "assignment before command" syntax not work to set `IFS` to a different value for the duration of the single command?  It appears you must change the value of `IFS` first with a separate command.

Comment: This might help: [Using IFS with echo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57627024/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `IFS` affects the parsing (tokenization, word-splitting) of a command, so it must be set before that command is parsed. This is why `IFS=a echo "$*"` can only use the original `IFS`, not `a`.

It's a somewhat similar case to `FOO=bar echo $FOO` not echoing `bar`. `$FOO` is substituted (empty) and then the command, with it's variable assignment is executed.

Comment: Thanks.  So the only way to reset it for one cmd is to save the old value, set to new value, execute cmd, then set back to old value, correct?

Comment: @Jonah Correct, and you will find many scripts doing exactly that with `IFS` when they only temporarily need to use it.

Comment: It's either that, or scope it to a subshell, or do things a different way entirely (`printf -v outvar '%sa' "$@"; echo "${outvar%a}"`, f/e).

Comment: @Jonah: a subshell with its own environment might help: `set -- 1 2 3; (IFS=a; echo "$*"); echo "$IFS"`

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus, makes sense now.